# foundation json issues with panini

Tags: json, zurb-foundation

Under my src in foundation, I have a data, created new json file. When I tag it with {{file}}, doesnt show in my index. html when I do npm run start.

I did, data: src/data added gulp watch
no results.

```
function pages() {
  return gulp.src(['src/pages/**/*.html', '!src/pages/archive/**/*.html'])
    .pipe(panini({
      root: "src/pages",
      layouts: "src/layouts",
      partials: "src/partials",
      helpers: "src/helpers",
      data: "src/data"
    }))
    .pipe(inky())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));

function watch() {
  gulp.watch('src/pages/**/*.html').on('all', gulp.series(pages, inline, browser.reload));
  gulp.watch(['src/layouts/**/*', 'src/partials/**/*']).on('all', gulp.series(resetPages, pages, inline, browser.reload));
  gulp.watch(['../scss/**/*.scss', 'src/assets/scss/**/*.scss']).on('all', gulp.series(resetPages, sass, pages, inline, browser.reload));
  gulp.watch('src/assets/img/**/*').on('all', gulp.series(images, browser.reload));
  gulp.watch('src/data/**/*.{js,json,yml}').on('all', gulp.series(resetPages, pages, browser.reload));
  gulp.watch(['../scss/**/*.scss', 'src/assets/scss/**/*.scss', 'src/data/*']).on('all', gulp.series(resetPages, sass, pages, inline, browser.reload));
  gulp.watch('src/data/**/*.json').on('change', gulp.series(resetPages, pages, inline, browser.reload));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but I have slash at line ends.

```
function pages() {
  return gulp.src('src/pages/**/*.{html,hbs,handlebars,php}')
    .pipe(panini({
      root: 'src/pages/',
      layouts: 'src/layouts/',
      partials: 'src/partials/',
      data: 'src/data/',
      helpers: 'src/helpers/'

    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(PATHS.dist));
}
```